# Linux live USB with working sleepmode searched for secure erase SSD

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, suspend, ssd, secure-erase

I want to secure delete a SSD drive.

I tried to perform the secure delete order with hdparm, but the drive is frozen. Loading the Samsung bootimage lead to the same result: The dialogue says the drive is frozen and a hot plug is recomended. This is not a good option because the drive is installed in an laptop.

I also tried to boot up parted magic. When the pc is send to sleep to unfreeze the drive it wakes up to a black screen. No interaction is possible from this point. I reboot from here with magic syskeys. I do not want to perform a hot plug.
So: Is there a live USB system in which the sleeping operation is well (and wake) supported to get the SSD unfrozen and the start secure delete afterwards with hdparm?

Comment: Have you tried suspending and waking from an Ubuntu live USB?

Comment: Yes. After pushing a key on the Keyboard the computer seems to wake but the screen keeps black. Maybe the problem is connected with the nouveau driver. I can the start the system only with `nomodeset`  as boot option.